#  Сравнение элементов

Tags: java

Как корректно записать код что бы не возникло ошибки

```
public boolean containsAll(MyDeque<? extends E> deque) {
String s="10";
for(int i=0;i<deque.size();i++){
s.equals((? extends E)deque(i));  //выдает ошибку 
}
```

//"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to MyDeque<capture#2-of //? extends E>"

```
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то метод equals принимает в качестве параметра тип Object, так что приведение типа вам не нужно. Только вот непонятно, с чем вы собираетесь сравнивать строку?

Comment: `(? extends E)` — это не тип. И почему вы сравниваете со строкой? Объясните, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: (? extends E)deque(i) вот это неправильная конструкция

Comment: В качестве параметра метод containsAll принимает коллекцию.
Необходимо проверить существует ли в коллекции элемент s;
s.equals(deque[0]) - так же выдает ошибку описанную выше. как извлечь элемент из очереди?
MyDeque<? extends E> - Mydeque может быть genericom типа E и любого его наследника? если в качестве generica будет тип String то при извлечении элемента достаточно обернуть в (String)?

Comment: А у вас коллекция строк или нет? Почему не `MyDeque<String>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-превых, выражение `deque(i)` в корне неверно. В Java круглые скобки () означают вызов функции. `deque` - не функция, `deque` - объект. Для получения i-го элемента `deque` нужно вызвать соответствующий метод. Так как `deque` - объект класса `MyDeque`, который вы наверняка написали сами, то я затрудняюсь сказать, какой именно метод вам нужен и есть ли он у вас вообще.

Во-вторых, приведение типов с помощью выражения `(? extends E)` в корне неверно. Запись "`? extends E`" допускается только в объявлении дженериков. В вашем случае приведение типов должно выглядеть так: `(E)`.